# How to properly generate summarizing text files in Python

Tags: python

So I need tips on how to generate and format .txt output files in Python.

Now, I have a script that takes input and outputs calculations.
I would like a .txt file that summarizes all calculations and results.

My problem is NOT how to create a file. I need tips on how to properly write the code so that the .txt files look proper and tidy.

```
# input

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

# output

d = 4
e = 5
f = 6


path = 'C:\Python27'
name = 'Test'
foo = open ( '%s/%s.txt' % (path , name), 'w')

foo.write('\t\t%s\n\n\n' %name)
foo.write('\t\t--------------Input-----------------\n\n')
foo.write('a = %r  \"Input \'a\'" \nb = %r  \"Input \'b\'\" \nc = %r  \"Input \'c\'\" \n\n\n ' % (a, b, c))
foo.write('\t\t--------------Output-----------------\n\n')
foo.write('d = %r  \"Output \'d\'\" \ne = %r  \"Output \'e\'\" \nf = %r  \"Output \'f\'\" \n\n\n ' % (d, e, f))
foo.close()
```

This yields this result:

```
        Test


    --------------Input-----------------

a = 1  "Input 'a'" 
b = 2  "Input 'b'" 
c = 3  "Input 'c'" 


    --------------Output-----------------

d = 4  "Output 'd'" 
e = 5  "Output 'e'" 
f = 6  "Output 'f'"
```

There has to be an easier way to do this?

I have 40 parameters plus text to write...

Comment: Why are your parameters not in a dictionary or list then? [Keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: Would strongly suggest you to use string formatting .eg. `{0}\t{1}".format(a,b)`

Comment: Yes guys. This is precisely the sort of tips I am looking for! Is there a place with a collection of these tips? Sort of dos and don'ts?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - haha, because I don't really know what I am doing :) I will look into that!  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c', 3} #dictionaries are better for what you need to do
outputs = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f': 6} 

foo = open('test.txt', 'wb')

foo.write('\t\t test \n\n\n')
foo.write('\t\t--------------Input-----------------\n\n')

for input, value in inputs.items(): #items will generate a list of tuples
    foo.write('{0} = {1}'.format(input, value)) #or any other formatting you'd like
    foo.write('\n')
```

Then do the same for outputs.

Comment: Thank you for showing an example. This looks very promising! :D